# Absolute or Relative divs won't stay in one spot

Tags: css

I have a <kbd>[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/jlnewnam/H8Sth/1/embedded/result/)</kbd> here.

***Note**
This uses isotope, but it's not functioning properly in JSFiddle. So, when you use the fiddle, it's not going to filter, but it will highlight the appropriate `<div>`s accordingly.

However, that's not the issue... when you type in one of the keywords (shown on the fiddle), it narrows down to a couple of documents. Then, when you hover over the doc, it displays an "Email" button, and a "PDF" button.

You an also hover over the docs before searching and see what' I'm talking about.

Depending on the div it's displayed in, the images (which are backgrounds on different elements) are showing up in different spots.

I can't get them to display in the same place on each of the orange squares.

**Here's the CSS for the main `<div>`...**

```
.iso-container li   {
  width: 140px;
  height: 140px;
  margin: 5px;
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  background: #f8981d;
  font-size: 0.01em;
  color: #f8981d;
  background-image: url(../images/doc-pdf.png);
  -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 1.2em;
  -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 1.2em;
  -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 1.2em;
  -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 1.2em;
      -moz-border-radius-topright: 1.2em;
      -moz-border-radius-topleft: 1.2em;
      -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 1.2em;
      -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 1.2em;
          border-top-right-radius: 1.2em;
          border-top-left-radius: 1.2em;
          border-bottom-right-radius: 1.2em;
          border-bottom-left-radius: 1.2em;
            border-radius: 1.2em;
            behavior: url(pie/PIE.htc);
}
```

**And here's the CSS for the image elements that appear on hover...**

```
.popover-email {
  display: none;
  width:  27px;
  height: 24px;
  background-image: url(../images/bxw_email.png);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  position: fixed;
  top: 65px;
  left: -100px;
}

.item:hover .popover-email { display: block; }

.popover-pdf {
  display: none;
  width:  25px;
  height: 27px;
  background-image: url(../images/pdf-button.png);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  position: fixed;
  top: 65px;
  left: -30px;
}

.item:hover .popover-pdf { display: block; }

.item:hover {
  z-index: 10;
}
```

Comment: It's because `.doc *` has `position:absolute`.  If you remove that and take off the negative `left` they will all be in the same place relative to their parent `li`

Comment: @ChrisRockwell Worked great. Missed that `.doc` div. Much Thanks! Please make that an answer and I'll take care of you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`position:absolute` on `.doc *` is the culprit.  Remove that and then adjust your `top` and `left` positioning and you'll be set.

Comment: Thanks again. There's another question about this project [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18836693/display-hover-images-only-in-certain-state) if you're interested.