# Display hover images only in certain state

Tags: css, hover

**Tried matching the title to the question as best I could**

I have a fiddle <kbd>[here](http://jsfiddle.net/jlnewnam/H8Sth/2/embedded/result/)</kbd>...

In the current state you see the orange `<div>`s, and when hovered over, I don't want the hover images to show (`.popover-email` and `.popover-pdf`).

When searched, and a match is found, then li.match element is enabled, and then I want the images to be visible on hover... just not in their native state.

I can't seem to put it together to do what I want. Not sure if it's even possible yet.

**Here's the CSS for that area of the page...**

```
.iso-container li.match {
    padding-top: 20px;
    background: #f8981d;
    padding-left: 5px;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: .7em;
}

.iso-container li.miss  {
    opacity: 0.3;
}


.popover-email {
  display: none;
  width:  27px;
  height: 24px;
  background-image: url(../images/bxw_email.png);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  position: absolute;
  top: 95px;
  left: 25px;
}

.item:hover .popover-email { display: block; }

.popover-pdf {
  display: none;
  width:  25px;
  height: 27px;
  background-image: url(../images/pdf-button.png);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  position: absolute;
  top: 95px;
  left: 88px;
}

.item:hover .popover-pdf { display: block; }


.item:hover {
  z-index: 10;
}
```

Does that make sense?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You only need to change `item:hover` to `item.match:hover` and presto.

```
.item.match:hover .popover-email { display: block; }
.item.match:hover .popover-pdf { display: block; }
```

### [See the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jasny/H8Sth/6/embedded/result/)

Comment: You're welcome. If your problem is solved, please use the (green) checkmark next to this answer. Thanks.

Comment: I know. I've got less than a minute.

Answer (score 1):

After a skim of your JS I see that you're adding a class called `match` when a search is correct.

So why not specify your `:hover` CSS to execute when this class is found:

```
.item.match:hover .popover-email { display: block; }
```

Comment: Thanks George! Great answer, but Arnold came through one minute before you. Thanks again!